# Intellij12 - idea64 not starting with java 8

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-12

I updated week my computer to java8 and until that time I was able to start idea64.exe. After my update to java 8 I'm not able to start idea64 any more.
[image]

The java_home is prooperly set and working
[image]

The 32bit idea is working properly, has anybody facing this issue also?
How can I solve it to working properly again?

Comment: Did you install 32-bit Java or 64-bit?

Comment: I thought I installed 64bit, jre-8u92-windows-x64.exe from oracle website.